# Content does not show when on mobile device? My media queries dont seem to be the issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am having a problem with my CSS where the content of my website does not show on Mobile devices. I don't have a problem when I test on my computer using the inspect element and change it to mobile device it works. But when I use the inspect element and change it to mobile prior to navigating to my website - it only shows the backgrounds and none of my text or other elements. I'm using bootstrap and I'm not sure exactly whether I should be checking my javascript or CSS for why the content is not appearing, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already use the `meta-scale` in your head-part?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into the  section of your HTML document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

If this doesn't work please give us a link or a screenshot of what's happening.